# Resizing columns in NSOutlineView without showing headers

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I've an outline view with two columns. I want to allow my users to resize both columns but it doesn't seem to be possible without also displaying the column headers. Anyone succeeded in doing this?

Comment: The standard resizing interface involves dragging between column headings.  What other resizing interface do you want?

Comment: Ideally I'd be allowed to resize even though column headers aren't visible. They spoil the layout I'm building.

Comment: How do you want to trigger resizing then?

Comment: Resizing the column, for example, but without the headers.